# Dot Net framework prerequsite check in wix not detecting properly for 64 bit machine

Tags: c#, wix, wix3.9

I am developing a setup for my application and i need to build a setup for it. I am using wix to build the setup and in that i need to validate whether dot net framework has installed or not.
 here is my previous code

```
<Property Id="NETFX40CLIENTREDIST">
  <RegistrySearch
    Id="NetFx40ClientRedist"
    Root="HKLM"
    Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client"
    Name="Version"
    Type="raw" />
</Property>
<Condition
  Message="Microsoft .Net Framework 4 Client Profile was not installed. 
 Please download and install from 
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17113 ">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFX40CLIENTREDIST>="10.0.30319"]]>
    </Condition>
```

**This condition works good on 32 bit machine and in some 64 bit machine its not detecting even if dot net framework has installed its showing this validation.**

I need my condition to be shown only if dot net framework has not installed.I need to support DotNetFramework 4 and above. Especially 4.6.1 must be supported too .

Answer (score 1):

The detection mechanism has already been implemented in the [WixNetFxExtension](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/check_for_dotnet.html). This will give you these properties: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html

Comment: :there they have only mentioned to detect a single framwork.I want to detect  framework installed 4 and above (ie( 4.5,4.6 and later )